# About SOFA For Unity SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Dear friends Hello everyone I encountered some problems when using SOFA for Unity SDK plug-in, import plug-in, Unity reported an error, the error is as follows:

```
ExecutionEngineException: String conversion error: Illegal byte sequence encounted in the input.
SofaUnityAPI.SofaContextAPI.DisplayMessages () (at Assets/SofaUnity/Plugins/SofaUnityAPI/SofaContextAPI.cs:429)
SofaUnity.SofaContext.DoCatchSofaMessages () (at Assets/SofaUnity/Scripts/SofaContext.cs:564)
SofaUnity.SofaContext.ReconnectSofaScene () (at Assets/SofaUnity/Scripts/SofaContext.cs:618)
SofaUnity.SofaContext.Init () (at Assets/SofaUnity/Scripts/SofaContext.cs:405)
SofaUnity.SofaContext.StartSofa () (at Assets/SofaUnity/Scripts/SofaContext.cs:312)
SofaUnity.SofaContext.Awake () (at Assets/SofaUnity/Scripts/SofaContext.cs:258)
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: The problem is that I run the scene and there is no response, and it is because of this error that the scene runs unresponsive

Comment: So edit your question to include this and clarify the problem.